# 2D avatar portrait images based on 3D model in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d

Is it possible to generate 2D avatar portrait pictures(.png) of 3D characters/objects in unity, and would it be advisable.

During my game, I want to dynamically generate and show a list of characters/objects in a scrollbar UI component, and i'm too lazy to actually go make these 2D images manually.

**I want to know if it is possible to generate a list of character/object portraits from a set of 3D prefabs in to display**, or if it would be more advisable to rather manually generate pictures and add the pictures to the as assets.

Apart from being lazy, this will then also be a lot easier to add characters/objects to my project and to maintain them if they are changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script like this to take a pic of the scene. So you could instantiate somewhere the gameobject, with a specific orientation, background, illumination, distance to the camera... Then you take the screenshot and store it somewhere with your other assets.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class HiResScreenShots : MonoBehaviour {
     public int resWidth = 2550; 
     public int resHeight = 3300;

     private bool takeHiResShot = false;

     public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height) {
         return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png", 
                              Application.dataPath, 
                              width, height, 
                              System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
     }

     public void TakeHiResShot() {
         takeHiResShot = true;
     }

     void LateUpdate() {
         takeHiResShot |= Input.GetKeyDown("k");
         if (takeHiResShot) {
             RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
             camera.targetTexture = rt;
             Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
             camera.Render();
             RenderTexture.active = rt;
             screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
             camera.targetTexture = null;
             RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
             Destroy(rt);
             byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
             string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
             System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
             Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
             takeHiResShot = false;
         }
     }
 }
```